# Communication between multiple devices

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to make a turn based application. Such that users involved will perform some operation and when their turn is over then next user should get notification.

Now I will be showing standard message like "It's your turn". So, how can I trigger this notification from my device and pops up notification saved "locally".

I did some research and came across various options like Firebase cloud messaging, Firebase push notifications. But for Firebase push notifications, we need one extra server. Will I have to deploy server just for that?

And Can I use FCM for this?
Any help or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you think you need an extra server for push notifications. But yes, Firebase products can handle all of that. Kind of a broad question though as it's really going to come down to your specific use case. Go through the Firebase guides, write some code and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you are using any database for this (online) turn based application. It would be easy for you to trigger firebase notifications using firebase cloud  functions. [Check this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)
You can create a value in database suppose turn and update the value in database depending which user's turn. Every time using `cloud functions onUpdate` you can trigger and send notification to the user. in order to send notification to a particular user you have to save their token in your database.

Comment: I am using firebase reatime database as backend for my application. Thanks for your help.